# 3ds Max 2010 / 2012 workspace files parsing

Tags: xna, workspace, 3ds

We are in the process of parsing out what 3ds Max files we need to keep as "source" for an Xna Game engine application.

Necessarily, there are .X (ActiveX model files) we need to keep of course. That I understand.

However, our 3D developer bailed on us and left us in a lurch. I am now tasked with the inglorious task of parsing which files to keep.

We've got a bunch of utilities, PDF documentation and other, what I would consider, "noise" files comingling the necessary stuff, like .X, .MAX, .VRMESH (I think?) or other such files.

Any pointers on what to watch out for taking an inventory what we've got, need to keep, could get rid of, or at least archive (which we have anyway)?

Thanks...

Michael

Comment: well, I'm opening up some of the MAX files to get a flavor for what's going on. and wouldn't you know it, our 3D guy left a mess of things. which we somewhat knew. now I really know. we've got textures and stuff strewn about his C:\ in at least half a dozen different places, God only knows where to find them. and to make matters worse, it would appear 3ds MAX file format is binary not text, so it's not like we can edit the paths manually to start cleaning this mess up a bit. I don't think anyway.

Comment: at first blush, my assessment is that, even if textures and other requisite files are being used by multiple models, it is better for them to be in the same directory as the model you're working on. at the very least, in a path that the model can reach without going elsewhere. I mean, this is workspace organization 101 folks. something like this? 3ds Max users? Feedback? Thanks...

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a mess.  My guess would be to archive everything you can, and then keep any .x files...

Comment: on the surface yes, at least the .X files. However, I am of the opinion that the MAX, mesh, textures, etc, are all necessarily part of our "source code". Without them, we cannot reproduce the .X result, which leaves us in a horribly tenuous position.

Answer (score 1):

In 3ds Max there's a feature called Asset Tracking. It lets you see (and change) all the texture paths for the scene. Take the latest version of every 3ds Max scene, go through the asset list and copy each referenced texture to the desired folder. Note that it's possible to use relative paths here.

I'm sure next time you'll provide your artists with a directive on folder structure, source control and general organisation!.

Comment: Aranda, you're not kidding. Our senior guy there has already confessed fire him for not knowing what our (now-former) 3ds guy was doing. He didn't leave us in a great shape where folder structure is concerned... Sounds like my assessment and necessarily expectation however isn't too far off the mark. Thank you...